# Send visitor to page after the request is done

Tags: php, redirect

I'm creating a personal webpage Plex API so other people can see my movie/TV-serie collection if they are in the same network as my Plex server. The visitor can click on "Play now" to start the movie/TV-serie on Plex through the website.

My problem now is I don't know how I redirect the visitor twice! I want to start the request and then send the visitor back to the information page. The request looks like this: `http://MacPro.local:32400/system/players/192.168.1.6/application/playFile?path=http://mac-mini.local:32400/library/parts/438/file.m4v` (the URL is taken from theirs [HTTP Control API](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/HTTP_Control_API) page - mine is different of course) and when this request is done, the visitor will be redirected to `http://localhost:8081/plex/info/3890`.

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Here's the solution:

```
$ch = curl_init('the url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header("Location: http://localhost:8081/plex/info/3890");
exit;
```